# All folders in Outlook 2007 are syncing except inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-client

As the title says I am unable to sync my inbox.  I have made sure that the Cached Exchange mode is checked and I made sure that "send immediatly when connected" was checked for an auto sync, but the Inbox folder will not sync.  All the other folders will.

Just for clarification I used this as a guide [How to troubleshoot synchronization problems when you synchronize your Exchange Server mailbox with your .ost file in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842284)

Comment: Just for clarification I used this as a guide http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842284.

Comment: Did you get as far as deleting your OST file and having Outlook build a new one?  By the way...this probably belongs on Superuser.

Comment: Not to mention that it lacks any detail that would allow us to provide an answer. This is akin to me saying "My car won't start. It has gas in it and I made sure to turn the key in the ignition. Can you help me?".

Comment: Yeah I rebuilt the OST.  I went through all those steps listed.  And I honestly don't know where to turn to from here.  I am not sure what more detail can be explained.  Every Folder except the inbox will sync.  It's on an XP machine.  It's a fresh install.  The ost has been rebuilt.

Comment: It's Windows, so I assume you also rebooted it three times and waved a rubber chicken over it?